# Browser Alert In Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I disable Alert Box of the browser in the code, I mean I don't want my chromedriver to pop up an alert for any reason, .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `window.alert(...)` to another function (eg log to console)

```
WebDriver driver = createDriver();
driver.get("http://foo.bar.com");
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    String script = "window.alert = function(message) { console.log(message); };";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
}
driver.findElement(By.id("someButton")).click();
```

Comment: On certain click on button I get alert box , so will this code work on that.

Comment: Assuming this is the first thing you do, any subsequent `alert(...)` calls will call the new function and won't popup an alert box